# Puppeteer name resolution error on Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I have created a brand new free tier project, cloned [Puppeteer Firebase Functions demo](https://github.com/ebidel/puppeteer-functions) repository and only changed the default project name in `.firebaserc` file.

When I run the simple [test](https://github.com/ebidel/puppeteer-functions/blob/master/functions/index.js#L23) or version functions I get the correct result. When I open the `.com/screenshot` page without any parameter I get correct ("Please provide a URL...") response.

But when I try any url, i.e. `.com/screenshot?url=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google` I get `Error: net::ERR_NAME_RESOLUTION_FAILED at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google` thrown in response.

I tried looking for any name resolution errors related to Puppeteer but I could not find anything. Could this be a problem of using free tier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free Spark payment plan restricts all outgoing connections except those API endpoints that are fully controlled by Google.  As a result, I expect that puppeteer would not be able to make any outgoing connections to external web sites.

Comment: I have tested it with http://example.com/ as domain and it somehow worked, maybe because of size. Then I just enabled billing for Firebase and all Puppeteer functionality is working flawlessly.